# Create an array of a Class based on string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

I have created a class called "letter":

```
class Letter
{
    char letter{};
    bool guessed{ false };

    public:
        void setLetter(std::string);
};
```

and I would like to create an array of class "Letter". The size of the array should be the size of a user inputted string, and if possible, each letter of the string should be stored in 1 element of the letter object.
I have tried the following:

```
std::string word;
Letter test[] = word;
```

```
"initialization with {...} expected for aggregate object"
```

```
std::string word;
Letter test[word.length()]; // and then iterate through each element of the string
```

```
"expression must have a constant value"
```

EDIT:
Solved

```
std::string word;
std::vector<Letter> test;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    test[i].setLetter(word[i]);
}
```

Comment: Prefer [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) when you need a dynamically sized array.

Comment: could you use a `vector`?

Comment: @GenoC Definitely, I'm just more accustomed to arrays

Comment: `setLetter(std::string)` should probably be `setLetter(char);`

Comment: The `letter` member is `private`. Presumably `setLetter` is responsible for setting it. But it takes a whole `std::string` instead of just a letter. It isn't clear how it is intended to work, I can't imagine what it is supposed to do if the input is not exactly 1 letter. Did you mean to use `void setLetter(char)` instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I forgot to change it. Originally I thought I was going to have to call the function on a string, and parse the letters within the function

Comment: @RudyGoburt Then you can just do `test[i].setLetter('a')` to set the letter at index `i` to `'a'`, just as if `test` was an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern C++, the tool you should first look to when thinking of a dynamic array is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Here, you would use a `std::vector<Letter>`. In this case you could write `std::vector<Letter> test(word.length());` to make container that holds `word.length()` default constructed instances of the class `Letter`.

`std::vector` behaves mostly like an array. You can access elements the same way, by using `operator[]`. For example `test[1]` access the 2nd element whether `test` is a `Letter[]` array or an `std::vector<Letter>`. It has additional functions which you should familiarize yourself which are listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

In cases where the array's size is not dynamic (when it is known at compile time) it is still preferable to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). C style arrays have few use cases in modern C++ and should generally be avoided in favor of newer, safer alternatives.

Comment: "In modern C++, the tool you should first look to when thinking of a dynamic array is std::vector" ... with "modern", you mean past -1994? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, i also would use a vector for a dynamic size. The hard task, in my opinion is to convert the string into an array of Letters.
The Letter class should have a constructor wich accepts a char and stores it. Than you could do something like this:

```
std::vector<Letters> myVector;
for( char current : string )
{
    myVector.emplace_back( current );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your program to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which would be more preferable since it is much more flexible and easier to use. You could do something like this -

```
class Letter
{
    char letter{};
    bool guessed{ false };

    public:
        void setLetter(char c){
            letter= c;
        };
        char getLetter(){
            return letter;
        };
};

int main()
{
    int user_input;
    char tmp;
    std::cin>>user_input;
    std::vector<Letter> test(user_input);  // this will create an array which can hold user_input number of objects of given type - Letter
    std::cout<<"enter letters :\n";
    for(int i=0;i<user_input;i++){
        std::cin>>tmp;
        test[i].setLetter(tmp);            // read input letter into each element(which is object of Letter)
    }
    for(int i=0;i<user_input;i++){
        std::cout<<test[i].getLetter();    // output the read letter
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT :**

```
4
abcd
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
enter letters :
abcd
```

---

1. Here, you use a vector of Letter in which I am just reading input into each element of the vector( where each element will be an object of `Letter` class) and then I am just outputting the read value. You could modify the above program to suit your needs.
2. Another change that I made is in the parameter which `setLetter` takes in. Since it is setting the `letter` variable of the object of class `Letter`, so it should take a character as a parameter and then set the character as the value of the letter. I have just added `getLetter` which just returns the letter for printing.
3. If you don't want to use vector, you could go with an array with declaration syntax like -

   ```
    Letter* test = new Letter[user_input];
   ```

   But, in C++, vectors are the preferred way to go and arrays should be avoided since vector are similar to an array with added functionalities and flexibility.